# Read lines "in"

Tags: python, line

Update. I figured it out. Something wrong with the line ending format. After I changed the format, the codes worked well. Thanks for all suggestions.

I would like to search specific strings in a text file.
Here is my code.

```py
fhand = open('mbox.txt')
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith('From:'):
        print (line)
```

However, instead of showing email address like

```py
From: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
From: louis@media.berkeley.edu
```

It showed nothing. What is the problem? Thanks!!

Comment: Could you provide a some lines of the text file?

Comment: Either there are no lines in the file, or none start with `'From:'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the example you provided in a file and use it instead of `mbox.txt`. It works.

It could be that you're using the wrong file, it is locked or you don't have the privileges to read from it. Or maybe you have some hidden unicode character before `From:`, either in the code or in the file.

Also you should always close the file, or use a `with` statement:

```
with open('mbox.txt') as fhand:
    for line in fhand:
        ...
```

Comment: if there were permission problems there would be an error

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I actually found the problem. The file I downloaded did not included correct line ending formats. After I modified with it, it showed the correct output.